# Combine two datatable with common column c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, merge, datatable

I have two table as below
Table1

```
   IntervalID(pK)
       1
       2
       3
```

Table 2

```
IntervalID  Name
1           XXX
```

Output should be (Table1+Table2)

```
IntervalID  Name
1           XXX
2          NULL
3          NULL
```

I have done like below

```
Table1.Merge(Table2);
```

But it does not give desired output

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by using **Left join**, like the following code:

```
var result = (from t1 in table1
              join t2 in table2 on t1.IntervalId equals t2.IntervalId into leftedResults
              from leftedResult in leftedResults.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { t1.IntervalId, Name = leftedResult?.Name }).ToList();
```

Note that, you can't merge two DataTables that not have similar schemas.

**Left join** for DataTables :

```
var result = (from t1 in dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
          join t2 in dataTable2.AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<int>("IntervalId") equals t2.Field<int>("IntervalId") into leftedResults
          from leftedReult in leftedResults.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new { IntervalId = t1.Field<int>("IntervalId"), Name = leftedReult?.Field<string>("Name") }).ToList();
```

I hope you find this helpful.